# couldn't communicate with windows server 2016 from outside the network, but inside everything is ok

Tags: vmware-esxi, router, switch, vmware-vsphere, windows-server-2016

I have some virtual machines on the esxi, such as windows server 2016 and one windows 7 ultimate.
On the windows server, I have one active directory and it runs dhcp on it so it has a static ip address which I set.
windows 7 ultimate gets its ip address from the dhcp from windows server 2016.
Locally everything is ok and I can ping or create remote desktop connection to every virtual machines or esxi and etc.
But outside of the network I can't do this stuff with windows server 2016.

I have one router between the 2 networks. From the laptop computer in the network 2 I can't see windows server 2016. But I can see windows 7.
Even I can see esxi.

I can ping from windows server 2016, my laptop computer in the network 2 and it is ok, but reverse communication can't happen.

1. I can ping from virtual windows 7 my virtual windows server.
2. I can ping from local client every virtual machines.
3. I can ping from every virtual or other machines in the network 1, the machines on the network 2.
4. I can ping from network 2 the windows 7 or other machines on the network 1 except windows servers.

I want to be able to ping and create remote desktop communication to my windows servers in the network1 from network2 and I can't.

Any help to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the 2016 server has the default gateway set to the router. ;-)

Comment: oops, excuse me for this dumb question. i forgot to set the default gateway. thank you